# Fit stochastic differential equation to data

Tags: estimation, stochastic-processes

Could I have some review of the method I used to fit following SDE:

```
 dX = f(t) dt + s X dW
```

Fitting method:

1. Calculated sample for sdW from our data as: $sdW_t = (dX_t - f_t) / X_t.$
2. Calculated s from the sample variance, assuming zero mean.

   $s = \sqrt{\text{sample variance}} = 0.007$.
3. Performed t-test for the sample mean: It is significantly different from zero.

   sample mean $= -0.003.$

   Also: Shapiro null hypothesis is not rejected and qqplot gives reasonable fit, so the sample is reasonably normally distributed.
4. Then I stated for the sample: $sdW = A1\sim N(-0.003,0) + A2\sim N(0,s^²d_t)$.
5. Since dt=1 during calculation of the sample, I concluded that the SDE becomes:

   ```
    dX = [f(t) - 0.003 X] dt + 0.007 X dW$
   ```

Thank you in advance for a sanity check.

Note: I am aware of fitsde(), however we have no function for f(t), only data points. Above method seemed more accurate and straightforward than attempting fitsde with some fitted f(t) function.

Comment: What is $f(t)$? These types of equations are very common in finance and physics. In finance there are usually so called "non-arbitrage" constraints on $f(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question:
We simulated above system with some chosen parameters m and s (snssde function).
From simulated data we estimated m and s, first with fitsde function and then with above method. Above method works correctly, and its estimates are closer to true values than estimates from fitsde. Besides, in fitsde the Kessler method is the only one (out of four) that gives decent estimates.